# Will a PHP local variable passed by reference reliably survive outside a function?

Tags: php, php-internals

Basically in the case of working with large arrays it's convenient to pass `null` back if an error occurs since if `$array = null` then `$array[] = 1` is `[ 1 ]` and `null` is also usable in a callable context, ie. `function (array $array = null)` will accept `null` as an acceptable value. Basically `null` is convenient since you can easily identify it as an error if you have error handling code, but also easily ignore it if you don't care.

This is fairly straight forward in most cases, however there is a corner case where PHP doesn't really support it all that well and that's when passing back a reference in the context of a function that doesn't necessarily accept a reference but needs to pass null back sometimes, yet pass a reference back other times (most of the time this is not an issue since you're returning a reference to a instance variable but sometimes that's not the case). There's also the case of calling a function with a `null` value in a non awkward way.

The reason to pass the reference is obviously to save the trouble of copying the array around (especially when it's very large).

The following "solution"...

```
\error_reporting(-1);

function & nil()
{
    $nil = null;
    return $nil;
}

function & pass(array & $variable = null)
{
    return $variable;
}

function & check ()
{
    return nil();
}

$test = pass(nil());
$test = &pass(nil());

$test1 = &check();
$test1[] = 1;
$test2 = &check();
$test2[] = 2;

\var_dump($test1, $test2);
```

Works, but...

**My question is** Does PHP guarantee the local variable won't be garbage collected before all references to it are garbage collected? or is that undefined behavior.

Comment: question 1) which php version are you using? question 2) whaaaat?

Comment: avoid references when possible. They make your life miserable. And returning null is a well known anti-pattern because it forces is_null checks all over your code. A function should return one type only.

Comment: @Ben PHP version is whatever is latest stable version. So at this time 5.4.x.

Comment: "Only return references when you have a valid technical reason to do so" [ref](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php)

Comment: @Ben Do you know the answer to the question or not?

Comment: PHP will never GC anything until reference count is >0.

Comment: @RomanNewaza I'm guessing you mean "while reference count is greater then 0." That's all I wanted to know, thanks! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP will never GC anything while reference count is greater than 0.